# how do i write action methods for partial views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I rendering a view partially like this.

```
<%= render(:partial => "index" ,:controller=>"controller_name") %>
```

so this will partially render **controller_name/_index.html.erb**

here is my doubt. can i write an action method for this _index. something like this?

```
class ControllerNameController < ApplicationController
  def _index
  end
end
```

thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No this should be

```
class ControllerNameController < ApplicationController
  def index
   render :partial=>'index'
  end
end
```

EDITED: Explaining my answer in detail - 
When you write a method `method_name` and you do not `render` ( `redirect_to`) anything, the controller will look for page `method_name.html.erb` by default.

However, using `render :partial` as shown below, the action will work with the partial instead.

For Example

```
class ControllerNameController < ApplicationController
  def some_method_name
   render :partial=>'index'  #look for the _index.html.erb
  end
end


class ControllerNameController < ApplicationController
  def some_method_name
   render :action=>'index'  #look for the index.html.erb
  end
end


class ControllerNameController < ApplicationController
  def some_method_name  #look for the "some_method_name.html.erb"

  end
end
```

Comment: so do you mean i should have both index and _index? two files in place of one..?

Comment: No when you write "render :partial=>'index'" then it will look only for _index.html.erb it simply don't care what is in index.html.erb